# Creating Google Cloud Function via Java API: Precondition check failed

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a Google Cloud Function using the [Java Client API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/cloudfunctions/v1) but keep getting a error with code 400 and message "Precondition check failed".

I understand that this is due to one of my input parameters being in the wrong form but there is no indication for which.

#### Calling code

```java
CloudFunction function = new CloudFunction();
function.setName("mytest1");
function.setAvailableMemoryMb(128);
function.setSourceArchiveUrl("gs://my-bucket/path/to/source.zip"); 
function.setRuntime("python37");
function.setEntryPoint("my_function_name");
function.setTimeout("450s");

String location = "projects/my-project-id/locations/us-east4";
cloudFunctions.projects().locations().functions().create(location, function).execute(); // exception thrown here
```

I have also tried setting the `serviceAccountEmail` of the function to that of the service account key I am using and also setting a `HttpsTrigger` too.

The [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudfunctions/v1/java/latest/) for this API says only the runtime is required however running it with just this set doesn't work either.

#### Error

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Precondition check failed.",
  "status" : "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function name is wrong.

```
function.setName("mytest1");
```

It should be like

```
function.setName("projects/{project-id}/locations/{location}/functions/{your-function-name}")
```

Function names must be unique globally and match pattern projects/*/locations/*/functions/*

Please refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions).

Comment: Can you expand your answer to tell why the parameter should look like that, and how it would look like for OP's particular case?